# Spark output files naming scheme

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm trying to understand the naming scheme used by Spark when writing output files.
For example, I have the following output:

```
2019-11-21 04:41:57  478988224 part-00000-a0d2c1f3-9e8b-48ca-b347-7065e1f2de3c-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-11-21 04:41:57  369488615 part-00000-a0d2c1f3-9e8b-48ca-b347-7065e1f2de3c-c001.snappy.parquet
2019-11-21 04:41:57   61498975 part-00000-a0d2c1f3-9e8b-48ca-b347-7065e1f2de3c-c002.snappy.parquet
2019-11-21 04:41:57  478216284 part-00001-a0d2c1f3-9e8b-48ca-b347-7065e1f2de3c-c000.snappy.parquet
2019-11-21 04:41:57  367980988 part-00001-a0d2c1f3-9e8b-48ca-b347-7065e1f2de3c-c001.snappy.parquet
```

If we consider single file name
`part-00000-a0d2c1f3-9e8b-48ca-b347-7065e1f2de3c-c000.snappy.parquet` it has the following naming scheme: `part-<part-number>-<uid>-<c-part>.<compression>.<format>`

Where is `uid` part being taken from? Is it task id or something similar? What does `c-part` means? Does the naming scheme change based on the used `mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version"`?